# Вектор с умными указателями на унаследованные объекты

Tags: c++

Есть базовый класс `GameObject`

GameObject.h

```
#pragma once

#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject();
    GameObject(float x, float y, Vec2 direction);
    virtual ~GameObject();

    virtual float getX();
    virtual void setX(float value);

    virtual float getY();
    virtual void setY(float value);

    virtual float getRotation();
    virtual void setRotation(float value);
    virtual void rotateBy(float value);

    virtual void update(float deltaTime){};

protected:
    void calculateRotation();
    float x;
    float y;
    float rotation;
    Vec2 direction;
};
```

GameObject.cpp

```
#include "GameObject.h"


GameObject::GameObject():x(0), y(0), direction(0, 1), rotation(0)
{
}

GameObject::GameObject(float x, float y, Vec2 direction):x(x), y(y), direction(direction), rotation(0)
{
}

GameObject::~GameObject()
{
}

float GameObject::getX()
{
    return x;
}

void GameObject::setX(float value)
{
    x = value;
}

float GameObject::getY()
{
    return y;
}

void GameObject::setY(float value)
{
    y = value;
}

float GameObject::getRotation()
{
    return rotation;
}

void GameObject::setRotation(float value)
{
    rotation = value;
}

void GameObject::rotateBy(float value)
{
    direction.rotate(Vec2(0, 0), value);
    calculateRotation();
}

void GameObject::calculateRotation()
{
    rotation = MATH_RAD_TO_DEG(atan2f(direction.x, direction.y));
}
```

Класс `BulletModel`наследуется от `GameObject`

BulletModel.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"

class BulletModel: public GameObject
{
public:
    BulletModel(float x, float y, Vec2 direction);
    virtual ~BulletModel();

    void update(float deltaTime);

private:
    float speed;
    float damange;
};
```

BulletModel.cpp

```
#include "BulletModel.h"

BulletModel::BulletModel(float x, float y, Vec2 direction):GameObject(x, y, direction)
{
}

BulletModel::~BulletModel()
{
}

void BulletModel::update(float deltaTime)
{
    x += direction.x * speed * deltaTime;
    y += direction.y * speed * deltaTime;
}
```

Класс `TankModel` наследуется от `Unit` который наследуется от `GameObject`

Unit.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"

class Unit: public GameObject
{
public:
    Unit(int health);
    virtual ~Unit();

    virtual void update(float deltaTime) {};

protected:
    int health;
};
```

Unit.cpp

```
#include "Unit.h"


Unit::Unit(int health):GameObject(), health(health)
{
}


Unit::~Unit()
{
}
```

TankModel.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Unit.h"

class WorldModel;

class TankModel: public Unit
{
public:
    TankModel(std::shared_ptr<WorldModel> world);
    virtual ~TankModel();

    void thrust(float deltaTime);
    void backing(float deltaTime);
    void rotateLeft(float deltaTime);
    void rotateRight(float deltaTime);
    void shoot(float deltaTime);
    void update(float deltaTime);

private:
    const float moveSpeed;
    const float rotationSpeed;

    std::shared_ptr<WorldModel> world;
};
```

TankModel.cpp

```
#include "WorldModel.h"
#include "TankModel.h"
#include "BulletModel.h"
#include "GameScene.h"

TankModel::TankModel(std::shared_ptr<WorldModel> world):
    Unit(100),
    moveSpeed(50),
    rotationSpeed(3),
    world(world)
{
}

TankModel::~TankModel()
{
}

void TankModel::thrust(float deltaTime)
{
    x += direction.x * moveSpeed * deltaTime;
    y += direction.y * moveSpeed * deltaTime;
}

void TankModel::backing(float deltaTime)
{
    x -= direction.x * moveSpeed * deltaTime;
    y -= direction.y * moveSpeed * deltaTime;
}

void TankModel::rotateLeft(float deltaTime)
{
    rotateBy(rotationSpeed * deltaTime);
}

void TankModel::rotateRight(float deltaTime)
{
    rotateBy(-rotationSpeed * deltaTime);
}

void TankModel::shoot(float deltaTime)
{
    world->addBullet(x, y, direction);
}

void TankModel::update(float deltaTime)
{
}
```

Создаю контейнер `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>> models;`

Объекты `std::shared_ptr<TankModel>` в него положить можно, а объекты `std::shared_ptr<BulletModel>` нельзя.

Выдает ошибку

```
WorldModel.cpp(34): error C2664: 'void std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const std::shared_ptr<GameObject> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<BulletModel>' to 'std::shared_ptr<GameObject> &&'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=std::shared_ptr<GameObject>
2>          ]
2>  WorldModel.cpp(34): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr<BulletModel>' to 'std::shared_ptr<GameObject>'
2>  WorldModel.cpp(34): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Почему?

Comment: Приведите полный текст сообщений об ошибке.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow обновил исходное сообщение.

Comment: Попробуйте просто написать GameObject *p = new BulletModel; Что скажет компилятор? А вообще-то требуется минимальный проверяемый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Может `GameObject` не является публичным базовым классом для `BulletModel`?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, что такое [mcve] и попробуйте реализовать его в виде **единого** файла исходного кода. Помещение `shared_ptr` производного класса в вектор из `shared_ptr` базового, должно [работать](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VeQ3Sy0UmJtfk2wx).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow пожалуй мне стоило сразу попробовать привести сырые указатели друг к другу... Проблема оказалась в том, что в заголовочном файле я использовал предварительную декларацию для класса `BulletModel`, а в файле реализации не включил `BulletModel.h` . Странно, что при этом компилятор выдает не "incomplete type"

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась весьма нелепой, однако трудно опознаваемой по ошибкам компилятора. Я следовал совету по использованию в заголовочных файлах предварительных деклараций, вместо включений, а сами включения переносить в файлы реализаций, чтобы избежать циклических включений.

Если честно, я не знаю насколько данная рекомендация уместна, но пока что она похожа на единственный способ решения проблемы с циклическими включениями.

Предварительную декларацию я выполнил, а вот включить файл заголовка в реализацию забыл. Обычно в этих случаях компилятор выводил ошибку "Incomplete type", которая сразу давала понять в чем проблема, но выданная в этот раз "невозможность привести типы", сбивала с толку.